# $tP(X>t)$ converges to zero if $X$ has a finite mean.

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that a random variable $X$ has a finite mean. I would like to show that $tP(X>t)$ converges to zero, as $t$ goes to infinity; I have tried to use the Markov inequality, but it does not seem to work (can be used to show that $tP(X>t)$ has a finite limit, but not necessarily zero.)

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the limit exists, it must be zero, since otherwise you would not have $X\in L^1$.
Assuming that $X$ is a non-negative random variable,
$$ E[X]=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\mathbb{P}[X>r]\,dr $$
but $\frac{c}{r}$ is not an integrable function over $(a>0,+\infty)$ if $c\neq 0$.

Comment: @Henry: you're right, now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

For $t\ge 0$
$$0\le tP(X>t)=\int_t^\infty t \, dP(X\le x)\le \int_t^\infty X \, dP(X\leq x)\to 0$$ as $t\to \infty$ since $E(X)$ is finite.

Answer (score 0):

[As noted by @A.S., we may assume that $X\ge 0$.]

For each $t>0$ the random variable $Y_t:=t\cdot 1_{\{X>t\}}$ is dominated by the integrable random variable $X$. Also,  $\lim_{t\to\infty} Y_t=0$ on $\{X<\infty\}$, hence almost surely. By the Dominated Convergence Theorem, $t\Bbb P[X>t] =\Bbb E[Y_t]\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$.